# How to show attribute before product title?

Tags: magento2.3

This is the `attributes.phtml` located in `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view` which shows additional attributes:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
    <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('More Information') ?></caption>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?></th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>           
                
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I try to use this code for getting the attribute `modell` in the `title.phtml` located in `\app\design\frontend\Company\Vendor\Magento_Theme\templates\html` but it doesn't work:

```
if ($block->$_data['label'] = 'modell'):
```

The code for `title.phtml` is:

```
<?php if ($title): ?>
<div class="page-title-wrapper<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo $cssClass; ?>">
    <h1 class="page-title"
        <?php if ($block->getId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        echo $block->getId(); ?>" <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()): ?>
            aria-labelledby="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo $block->getAddBaseAttributeAria(); ?>"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
        

        $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
        $_product = $block->getProduct();
        if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()):
            foreach ($_additional as $_data):
                if ($block->$_data['label'] = 'modell'): //Tried here
                    echo $block->escapeHtml($_data['label']);
                    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']);
                endif;
            endforeach;
        endif;
    
        
        echo $title ?>
    </h1>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

How can I get this work? Thanks

Edit:

I want to display this attribute for the product which has the `attribute_code` `modell`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the `=` in condition by `==`

This doesn't make any sense in php

```
    if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()):
        foreach ($_additional as $_data):
            if ($block->$_data['label'] = 'modell')
```

What you want is probably

```
    if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()):
        foreach ($_additional as $_data):
            if ($_data['label'] == 'modell')
```

Also this is fine but might be miss understood

```
if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData())
```

Prefer

```
$_additional = $block->getAdditionalData();
if($_additional)
```

Comment: Thanks now it is working without errors but I get no result. I updates my question, can you please have a look if I can get the attribute with this query? Thanks

Comment: `$product->getModell()` should get you the value you want from the product. Magento 2 use "magical" getter / setter.  So if you have a product attribute `toto` you can use `getToto()` and setToto(....)`

Comment: I tried but gives me an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getModell() on null`

Comment: That means your product is not recovered properly.